# Question with accepted answer got destructfully edited by original author

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks, ethics

During some checking around on the answer, I noticed that one question looked unfamiliar to me.

Interestingly, the question, that was up yesterday, got fully changed, and an answer got accepted.

The question itself doesn't make any sense anymore, but since it was the original author who changed it, I am reluctant to rollback the edit (abusing newly gotten powers ...)

Should I flag the question for deletion, suggest the rollback, or simply respect the original author's apparent wishes? The quality of the question is now 0, containing meaningless tags (compared to the original one).

The interesting part about all this, is that quite some users did their best to answer the question (yes, including me), so what to do about this?

[The question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489184/no-not-at-all-nothing).

And as an update, he might have tried to erase his previous question, after he got flagged for a similar question as a duplicate, which can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500603/how-do-i-create-a-fixed-length-list-of-random-values-within-a-given-range-withou

Comment: @gnat I do have the reputation points, just i am new at it. The answers provided there however, did help me, as did those from ShadowWizard, so thanks :)